# Adding a product catalog to google sites that reads data from a Google Sheet and is public facing

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic-content, sites, product-catalog, xenocode

I have had enough of the issues with WordPress and am trying to come up with a replacement for a Ecommerce site. We are a very small business and so limited funds.

I have a third party provider that handles the shopping cart that I have been using for 10+ years and so all I need to do is embed product links that update the cart.

To confirm if Google Sites is a viable option I have a couple of questions:

- Can you have a public facing google site that surfaces data from a Google Sheet,
- Can you dynamically generate:
- Product list pages for categories etc,
- Individual product details pages.
- Can you embed product images from google docs in the product details pages.
- Similar to products we have a series of blog posts with articles and UTube videos which we could store in a combination of google sheet and/or documents in google docs if needed.
- We would like to have a search option that surfaces products and blog posts based on a search term.

I have reasonable programming knowledge of JavaScript, extensive VBA knowledge and played a little with AppScripts however I would like it to be as close to no-code/low code as possible or I would be interested in using an add-on or investigate how we could develop an add-on that facilitates this.

I have reviewed a number of no-code/low code platforms but each one has hidden costs that make them not viable so some pointers on any charges Google may require would also be helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Mat

I just need some direction on whether it is possible and where to look for how-to's.